# Unable to set bash 5.1 as default on Mac

Tags: bash, macos, shell, homebrew

I installed bash-5.1 via Homebrew on my Macbook (M1-Monterey).

> sachetz$ /opt/homebrew/bin/bash --version
> GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (aarch64-apple-darwin21.1.0)

Added the path to /etc/shells file:

```
/bin/bash
/bin/csh
/bin/dash
/bin/ksh
/bin/sh
/bin/tcsh
/bin/zsh
/opt/homebrew/bin/bash
```

And ran the following command to set bash-5.1 as the default:

> sachetz$ chsh -s /opt/homebrew/bin/bash

However, when I restart terminal and run the `bash --version` command, I still see bash-3.2:

> sachetz$ bash --version
> GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin21)
> Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

But if I run `echo $BASH_VERSION`, I see bash-5.1

> sachetz$ echo $BASH_VERSION
> 5.1.16(1)-release

Running `which bash` gives:

> sachetz$ which bash
> /bin/bash

Running `echo $SHELL` gives:

> sachetz$ echo $SHELL
> /opt/homebrew/bin/bash

When I run an `echo $PATH` with zsh as the default, I see /opt/homebrew/bin:

> % echo $PATH
> /opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands

However, if I run the same after the chsh to Homebrew bash, I see:

> sachetz$ echo $PATH
> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands

I'm guessing the issue here is that `/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin` is not present in the $PATH after I switch the default to Homebrew bash and restart the terminal. So the question is, why is the path variable different between the two, and how do I fix the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Just needed to add `/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:` to the PATH variable in ~/.bash_profile like:

> export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:$PATH"

I suppose I missed this out as an installation step or something.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the profiles, I believe bash checks both `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`. Typically the $PATH are setup there.

For zsh, it looks at `~/.zshrc`.

Also, you can check to see Terminal > Preference > Shells open with... option in the Terminal app.

Comment: I added those paths to the PATH variable in the ~/.bash_profile file. Working as expected now. Didn't realise I had to add those manually.

Comment: @AaronT bash only uses ~/.bashrc for *non-login* interactive shells, and macOS' Terminal runs shells as login shells. So ~/.bashrc won't normally be sourced (unless you source it from your ~/.bash_profile, like I do).

Answer (score 0):

`which bash` looks for bash under your path and `bash --version` is running a new bash from your path. If your path points to /bin/bash first, they'll give that bash's path/version. This isn't the correct way to verify the current shell's version.

The `$BASH_VERSION` & `$SHELL` point to the current shell and looks like it is already running the correct version.

You could also try [new](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/8868edaf2250e09c4e9a1c75ffe3274f28f38581/NEWS) built-in variables, like

```
echo $EPOCHSECONDS
```